# XML Exception in PHP not being caught

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

My code snippet is below - as you can see, I have a try-catch block, but inspite of this, I still get an uncaught exception that terminates the entire application. What am I missing?

```
try {
    $cakeXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $parseSuccess = $cakeXml->xpath('//ParseSuccess');
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $response['parseSuccess'] = false;
    $response['errors']['ParseError'] = 'An unknown error occurred while trying to parse the file. Please try again';
    return $response;       
}

2014-12-16 22:45:12 Error: Fatal Error (1): Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object
2014-12-16 22:45:12 Error: [FatalErrorException] Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the error message more-carefully, you will see that it is not dieing on an `Exception`, but on a `Fatal Error`. A `try/catch` statement cannot catch a fatal error in PHP,  as there is no way to recover from a fatal error.

As for solving this issue, your error is telling you `$cakeXml` is a non-object. One solution would be to do something like this.

```
try {
    $cakeXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    if (!is_object($cakeXml)) {
        throw new Exception('simplexml_load_string returned non-object');
    }
    $parseSuccess = $cakeXml->xpath('//ParseSuccess');
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $response['parseSuccess'] = false;
    $response['errors']['ParseError'] = 'An unknown error occurred while trying to parse the file. Please try again';
    return $response;       
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. ok thanks - follow on question - how can I force the method to timeout or quit if a Fatal error occurs? Right now, the application hangs and the user is left waiting for a response. Or is this not possible?

Comment: @ChicagoSky I've added a way to handle this specific case, by checking if `$cakeXml` is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

DOMXPath methods i.e. xpath or evaluate does not throw exceptions. Hence, you will need to explicitly validate and throw the exception.

See below code snippet:

```
$xml_1= "";

try {    
    $cakeXml = simplexml_load_string($xml_1);        
    if ( !is_object($cakeXml) ) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Not an object (Object: %s)', var_export($cakeXml, true)));
    } else {        
        $parseSuccess = $cakeXml->xpath('//pages');                
        print('<pre>');print_r($parseSuccess);
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $ex->getMessage(), "\n";        
}
```